# how to pass variable from powershell script to an other step?

Tags: powershell, environment-variables, jenkins-pipeline

I use Jenkins and pipeline Jenkinsfile with a Windows agent. I want set a veriable from powershell in a 1st step and use this value in a 2nd step after.

**my pipeline is:**

```
def MSVERSION
pipeline {
    stages {
        stage('Clean workspace') {
            steps {
                deleteDir()
            }
        }
        stage('package') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def stdout = powershell(returnStdout: true, script: '''
                        $MSVERSION="1234"
                        write-host "MSVERSION is $MSVERSION"
                    ''')
                    println stdout
                }
            }
        }
        stage('deploy') {
            steps {
                script {
                    bat 'echo MSVERSION is ${MSVERSION}'
                }
                bat 'echo MSVERSION is ${MSVERSION}'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**but my result is:**

```
MSVERSION is 1234
MSVERSION is ${MSVERSION}
MSVERSION is ${MSVERSION}
```

**EDIT**

**I find a workaroud but is not my question today:**

in powershell I write a var.propertie file:

```
set-Content -path "var.properties" -Value "MSVERSION=$($VERSION)"
```

and in my script I read this var.properties file:

```
properties = readProperties file: 'var.properties'
echo "MSVERSION is ${properties.MSVERSION}"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bat 'echo MSVERSION is ${MSVERSION}'
```

does not do string interpolation, but this does:

```
bat "echo MSVERSION is ${MSVERSION}"
```